# Getting Error Of permission even thought i give it

Tags: android, permissions

I am getting error of location permission even though i put request permission in onCreate. after I put request permission application ask for permission after Crashing.

i put request permission in onCreate. after I put request permission application ask for permission after Crashing.

```
private boolean gpsInit() {
    mLocService = (LocationManager) 
   getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (mLocService != null) {
        mLocProvider = 
    mLocService.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (mLocProvider != null) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
  Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
      PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {



                return true;
            }
            mLocService.addGpsStatusListener(this);
            if 
  (mLocService.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

  gpsStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.status_gps_ready));
                return true;
            }
        }
    }


     gpsStatusTextView.setText
    (getString(R.string.status_gps_no_support));
    showDialog(NO_GPS_SUPPORT);
    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to get GPS PROVIDER");
    // todo disable gps controls into Preferences
    return false;
}
```

Log:

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity 
 {com.quad14.obdnewtry/com.quad14.obdnewtry.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3429)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3469)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
    at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.getProviderProperties(ILocationManager.java:1056)
    at android.location.LocationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.java:383)
    at com.quad14.obdnewtry.activity.MainActivity.gpsInit(MainActivity.java:679)
    at com.quad14.obdnewtry.activity.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:832)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1269)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6783)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3406
```

Inside Oncreate:

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
        }
    } else {
        // We have already permission to use the location
    }
```

getting Error at this line
   mLocProvider = mLocService.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

All I want is Application should ask permission at Lunch

Comment: did you add permission in manifests

Comment: It looks like you didn't handle permission requesting result and perform dangerous action before accepting permission. Try read official documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: place all your gps realated code inside `if permission has given part`

Answer (score 1):

make sure you add permission in manifest

Write the following in manifest file if you haven't.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: the "following" is missing

Comment: Sorry i am just new to writing answers so i just didn't know about the code block and indentation on stackoverflow.